# Websites passing to remote server

Tags: c#, javascript, security, tcp

I'm planning a project which will require different websites to pass non-personal data to the server for processing/storing in a database. My idea is to set up <strike>a 
very basic threaded TCP server (in C# running in the background on a server)</strike> IIS  and just have it wait for incoming connections. When a connection is made and the data is passed, I will have the web server determine whether or not to save to the database. I plan on saving static javascript files to my server (one for each website) and having the different websites reference them. These js files will handle the passing of data from the websites to my server.

I've never done anything like this, so I'd like to know if there are any major safeguards I need to implement while developing this. The data is not sensitive, so I don't need to encrypt it.

More specific questions:

1. I plan on verifying parameters once it reaches the server (like injection safeguards), but is it typical to also confirm the location of the request or the authenticity?
2. Should I make any attempt to hide where the javascript files are sending the data to? Again, it's not sensitive data, I'm just concerned exploits which I'm not familiar with when dealing with javascript -> server.
3. Is there a different way I should be going about this, given the basics of what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: not enough information, no code, no attempt, no problem to solve.

Comment: It's a question on theory and best practices, not a question on syntax or logic. I'm asking at a very basic level if there is anything to watch out for when passing data via javascript to a TCP server.

Comment: @Eclyps19, I'm not understanding the Javascript/TCP part. Javascript is (generally) a web language which runs over HTTP. While HTTP runs on top of TCP this is completely abstracted and you don't event think about it. When you say TCP the rest of us are thinking sockets but are you just talking about a webserver? If you are actually talking TCP then you're going to have to implement the HTTP protocol on your own which I don't really recommend.

Comment: Then you might want to research it on google, because this isn't a site for random advice.  When you're having a problem implementing something and need help solving it, that's when you ask here.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the response. The server which the javascript will be passing to is indeed going to be using sockets. I haven't considered the exact way in which I will be passing the data (I know of socketjs and JSocket), but I'm really just trying to get a one-way connection going between the website and a remote server. Is this not recommended?

Comment: @Eclyps19, to the best of my knowledge, all javascript-based socket programs actually use either Java or Flash behind the scenes. You say "websites" passing data and I'm assuming by that you mean "website visitor's browsers" and this seems like a lot of overkill just to send data. I would recommend just passing the data over HTTP using normal GET/HEAD/POST/whatever requests.

Comment: @Eclyps19, if you need to push the data out "seamlessly" then just look into asynchronous javascript (AJAX). Its what everyone else is doing, even the page we're on right now.

Comment: The only issue I see with that (and the reason I opted for static js files on my end) was because different websites will require different data to be sent, but different pages within a single website will send the same data. This way I could add the same code to each page within a single website, and if I ever needed to change it, I could just modify a single file on my end. Can I still efficiently implement the AJAX within a remote js file? Thanks

Comment: @Eclyps19, check out @Chris Lively's answer. Basically, have everyone include the same javascript. If you want a little control you can give everyone a unique id if you want, that's what Google does. On the server side the code that spits out the javascript can look at host headers to determine which server is sending the code and you can modify the javascript based on that. I don't think you need to deal with web services like he says but you can if you want.

Comment: Greatly appreciate you taking the time to clear a few things up for me (and allowing me to clarify the unclear in my original post). This has helped a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(3). Is there a different way I should be going about this, given the basics of what I'm trying to accomplish?

Yes, yes there is.  Under no circumstance would I consider taking the route you've outlined.  It adds a tremendous amount of code for exactly zero benefit.

Instead do this:

1. Have your primary server be a regular web server.  Let it serve the javascript files directly to the clients.
2. The other web servers should simply include a regular script reference to your server that is hosting the javascript.  This is no different than how google tracking works or even how jQuery is often delivered.
3. Your primary server should also have a set of web services exposed.  This will accept the information for processing.  Whether you use generic handlers (.ashx), web services (.asmx), or windows communication foundation (.wcf) is immaterial.

Under no circumstance do you bother with writing tcp level code in javascript.  You will pull your hair out and the people that end up maintaining this will at some point in the very near future delete it all anyway.

Use the traditional means.  There is zero reason to do things the way you've identified.

Beyond this, read @Frug's answer.  You can't trust the javascript once it reaches the browser anyway.  It will be read, opened, and potentially modified.   The only thing you can do is use SSL to ensure that the traffic isn't captured or modified between you and the end client browser.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did not mention that I had planned on building the TCP server in C# and just running it as a service in the background. My apologies for the confusion. As you said on point #2, I planned on simply adding a reference on the websites to my js files, and each will contain code specific to the website they are being referenced on. I'm used to coding in locked down environments, so handling connections in the open (like through js) is still new to me. With my clarification, is capturing the data through my own application/service based TCP server seem acceptable?

Comment: @Eclyps19, the whole purpose of a web server is to handle HTTP traffic. I really don't recommend rebuilding the wheel with your own. Unless you use Java or Flash you're limited to HTTP-only traffic anyway so let IIS or Apache handle the complicated connection, handshake, filtering, etc.

Comment: Makes sense and saves me time. I'll go ahead and use this for handling the data. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific you need to watch out for because there is nothing you can do to ensure that the javascript is secured from being modified... so operate under the assumption that they can override your javascript. That means you need to be sure to sanitize the inputs on the server side from sql injections.

If it's not sensitive and there's not a whole lot of data, you can even pass it by having your javascript shove it in the URL as a querystring (like a get method form). It can be really easy to debug stuff sent that way.

Comment: I like the simplicity of just throwing the data in the URL, but I need the data to be pushed out seamlessly, and the server I'm pushing it to is not the same server that the website is running on, so I would need some other behind the scenes processing to get the data sent out anyway.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what server is hosting the page. If you only need to pass simple, non-sensitive data to a server you can call a page like www.yourpage.com/process.php?value=1 and then in process.php read the value and process it how you want. This sort of thing is really easy to do with javascript because you are just adding strings to the end of the URL and you don't need to worry about posting forms. The downside is that it's not secure and anyone can pass data to it that way. But if that isn't an issue, I don't see a down side.